# How to find a bigger version number?

Tags: ruby

When compare two version strings, `to_f` does not work well:

```
 > "1.5.8".to_f > "1.5.7".to_f
  => false
```

string comparison is better, but not always correct:

```
 > "1.5.8" > "1.5.7"
  => true 

 > "1.5.8" > "1.5.9"
  => false 

 > "1.5.8" > "1.5.10" # oops!
  => true
```

How to compare version strings properly?

Comment: Break it in parts, cast parts to integers and compare them separately.

Comment: To compare string directly doesn't work well sometimes is because of its implementation: If the strings are of different lengths, and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length, then the longer string is considered greater than the shorter one.

So, according to the definition:

**'1.5.8' > '1.5.10' #=> true**, since the 4th char 8 > 1
**'1.5.1' > '1.5.10' #=> false**, since the 4th char 1 == 1 and latter string is longer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea: create a `Object#compare_by` method that behaves like `compare` (aka the spaceship operator [Object#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)) but takes a custom block:

```
class Object
  def compare_by(other)
    yield(self) <=> yield(other)
  end
end

>> "1.5.2".compare_by("1.5.7") { |s| s.split(".").map(&:to_i) }
#=> -1
```

You can also take a more specific approach still based on the `compare` method:

```
class String
  def compare_by_fields(other, fieldsep = ".")
    cmp = proc { |s| s.split(fieldsep).map(&:to_i) }
    cmp.call(self) <=> cmp.call(other)
  end
end

>> "1.5.8".compare_by_fields("1.5.8")
#=> 0
```

Comment: I did not know you could compare Arrays like this, great answer.

Comment: @oldergod: you can compare arrays with <=> but the `Comparable` module is not included by default so you cannot write `[1,2] > [4,2]`. I've never understood why. (Of course you can include it yourself)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd probably just use the [Versionomy](http://dazuma.github.com/versionomy/) gem, no need to reinvent this specific wheel IMHO.

Example:

```
require 'versionomy'
v1 = Versionomy.parse("1.5.8")
v2 = Versionomy.parse("1.5.10")
v2 > v1
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

First start off by splitting the different parts of the versions:

```
v1 = "1.5.8"
v2 = "1.5.7"
v1_arr = v1.split(".")
=> ["1", "5", "8"]
v2_arr = v2.split(".")
=> ["1", "5", "7"]
v1_arr.size.times do |index|
   if v1_arr[index] != v2_arr[index]
     # compare the values at the given index. Don't forget to use to_i!
     break
   end
end
```

Comment: This is not C, you know? You can write ruby :)

Comment: The fact that it is not C does not stop me to provide a solution that would be similar in C. I could not think of a way to provide a shorter solution in "ruby" style.

Comment: Check out @tokland's answer then. You might learn something new (I have).